# Trying to access Friends List api Alternatives - Need App Suggestions

Tags: facebook

So i am trying to make an app that involves reviewing your facebook friends, but i am aware of the facebook friends list restrictions, do y'all have any suggestions for alternatives or work arounds? I will take any and all options.

Comment: There are no alternatives or work arounds. You can only access information about people that granted permission to your app to access their information

Comment: Are there any alternatives that don't use Facebook? Like somehow finding users based on contact info?

Comment: If you want Facebook Friends there is no way. On a phone you can probably get the contacts but that is a completely different question.